# Not able to clean up a pip install in Openshift

Tags: python, pip, openshift

I am trying to set up a python app in Openshift. I'm using the python-2.7 cartridge.  One of my dependencies is `oauth2client`.

Whenever I try to do this, the installation of oauth2client tries to install cryptography, which then carries on for a long time with no output and then suddenly fails saying `remote end hung up unexpectedly.`

Subsequently I cannot install oauth2client because I get this error:

`pip can't proceed with requirement 'cryptography>=0.7 (from pyopenssl>=0.15.1->-r /var/lib/openshift/559b74805004469ff20000ae/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 6))' due to a pre-existing build directory.
remote:  location: /var/lib/openshift/559b74805004469ff20000ae/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/build/cryptography
remote: This is likely due to a previous installation that failed.
remote: pip is being responsible and not assuming it can delete this.
remote: Please delete it and try again.`

When I try to delete that directory, I find that `app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv` exists, but it has no build subdirectory.  Nevertheless I keep getting the same error.

How can I get `oauth2client` working?  How do I clean up the failed pip install?

I have already deleted and recreated the app once, only to face the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried ssh to the gear and run the `pip` manually? I have experienced similar problems but this solved it for me.

Comment: Yes, I did.  No luck there.  Eventually I just had to find a different module than `oauth2client` - I didn't actually need the cryptography bit, which is a dependency of `oauth2client` - and install that.  Oddly enough Openshift then claimed that cryptography was also installed!

Comment: I had a similar issue today with a different library. I had to run pip manually twice. The first time I got the error you had here, the second time it worked fine, as if pip cleaned up the build directory at the end of the first run.